# How to initialize a pointer to null

Tags: c++, c++11

There are three ways (that I'm aware of) to initialize a pointer to a null value :

### 1) Value initialization

```
T a = T(); // T is a pointer type
T a{};     // brace initializers don't suffer from the most vexing parse
```

Even though a `typedef` is required, this form is met in non generic code as well, eg

```
typedef int* ip; 
int *p = ip();
```

### 2) Set to `nullptr` manually

```
int *p = nullptr;
```

### 3) Set to a valid nullpointer-constant implicitly convertible to any pointer-type

```
int *p = NULL;
```

---

- **What are the pros and cons of each method ?**
- **Are there uses case where each method is considered best fitting?**

Comment: I think `T a{};` is a more terse way to value-initialize anything.

Comment: Note that `int *p = NULL;` will actually expand usually to `int *p = ((void*)0);`

Comment: @Casey Yes right, gets you around the most vexing parse

Comment: Your method three has a confused comment: `NULL` need not be `0`, just a valid nullpointer-constant implicitly convertible to any pointer-type.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No it won't, since that wouldn't compile. `NULL` must be `nullptr` or a zero-valued integer literal, to be convertible to any pointer type.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that would be a very low-quality (and in turn, nonconformant) library implementation. Because of the typing rules of C++, `void *` is not implicitly assignment-compatible with object pointer types (unlike in C).

Comment: @MikeSeymour That's what I've seen as the macro definition for `NULL` in many places, but you're right. In the [standard's reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) it claims that `NULL` is either simply `0` or `nullptr`.

Comment: `static T* p;` is initialized to `0` as well, same applies to global pointers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "That's what I've seen as the macro definition for NULL in many places" - in C, probably. Definitely not in C++.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant _"in C, probably."_ Could well be so.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Seems they restricted it in C++14, or maybe even when introducing `nullptr`...

Comment: Don't forget the naked literal zero: `0`, `0L`, `0LL`, `0u`, `0ul` and `0ull`.

Comment: My guess: The most idiomatic way (the only competitively short way is `=0`) is value-initialization using uniform-initialization.

Comment: @Deduplicator From what I see from the mentioned standard's reference I'd agree with you.

Answer (score 5):

Stroustroup always told us to us to us

```
 TYPE *var = 0 ;
```

In ye olde days of C++ there was little standardization of libraries. Doing

```
TYPE *var = NULL ;
```

would often give different results when the definition of NULL was not standardized. Some compilers picked up the C definition.

C++ needed

```
#define NULL (0)
```

to work right while C headers generally had

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)
```

Thus, 0 became the accepted method for setting null pointers.

With the standard changes, there might be a shift to nullptr.

Comment: Though for init (especially considering generic code), value-initialization might be (or become) even more prevalent.

Comment: @Deduplicator Only if the generic code does not know that `T` is a pointer. For `T*`, `T* foo = nullptr;` is still the most descriptive version.

Comment: @cmaster: debatable, I don't buy it. And in that case, `=0` looks good too.

Comment: C headers ?  Well, I've just looked in my K&R from 1979: it was already `#define NULL 0`

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
int *p = nullptr;
```

is the best, I think.

When you use the `typedef`, it's OK to use value-initialization. But, you can't use:

```
int *p = int*{};
```

or

```
int *p = int*();
```

However, you can use:

```
int* p = nullptr;
ip q = nullptr;
```

Using `nullptr` to initialize is valid in both forms. Hence, it's better to use it to initialize pointers.